# If i search trough my csv file the output comes serverval times

Tags: php, html, csv

If I typing Test1 in my form the output is than 5x Test1, If I typing Test2 in my form the output is that 4x Test2 etc. How can I solve this problem?

This is my csv file:

"Naam"

"Test1"

"Test2"

"Test3"

"Test4"

This is my search form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Test Test Test</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <form action="csv.php" method="post">
                <h3>Voer je naam in:</h3>
                <pre>
                    Naam:           <input type="text" name="Naam"><br>
                                    <input type= submit name="submit" value="Verzenden">
                </pre>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Test Test Test</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <form method="get">
            <?php
            if ( !empty ( $_POST['Naam']) ) {
                $naam = $_POST['Naam'];      
                $file_handle = fopen("Test.csv", "rb");
                $found = false;
                while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
                    $parts = fgetcsv($file_handle,4096,",");
                    $file_arr = preg_split ( "/\n/" , $file_content );
                    foreach ( $file_arr as $item ) {
                        if ( $parts[0] == $naam ) {
                            $found = true;                  
                            $resultaat = $parts[0];
                            }
                        }
                    $parts[0] = ucwords(strtolower($parts[0]));
                    if ( $found ) {
                        Print "Naam: ". $resultaat; echo "<br>";
                        }
                    }
                if ( !$found ) {
                    print "Not found";
                    }
                fclose($file_handle);
                }  
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you found it add a  `break;`(abortion of the loop) since you keep processing the file and `$found` is still true.

E:

`if ( $found ) {`

`Print "Naam: ". $resultaat; echo "<br>";`

`break;`

`}`

You set $found = true and never reset it. So it will stay true and since the file is not through every further loop will be running into that `if($found)` statemanet

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the meaning of the part "$file_arr = preg_split ( "/\n/" , $file_content );
        foreach ( $file_arr as $item ) {"

this seem to be some residue from previous implementation of code withou fgetcsv.